# For those who use American English, how do you use your dictionary for this?

Tags: american-english, dictionaries, compound-adjectives

Please DO NOT answer *this* question if you use British English. You might help by answering the *other* question I posted just before this one.

I have found examples suggesting there is a fundamental difference in the way the Oxford and Merriam-Webster dictionaries handle the punctuation of compound adjectives AFTER NOUNS.

I live in a small city in Indonesia and cannot go to a library to research this myself.

My understanding has always been that writers should **always** hyphenate (or not) compound adjectives after nouns in the same way as the expression is listed in their preferred dictionary.

That is not how CMOS does it with this example. The Merriam-Webster Dictionary (the one CMOS uses) defines the adjectival form of 'middle-class' with a hyphen. Yet CMOS at 7.85 states this is correct:

> the neighborhood is middle class

Can anyone describe a process to follow when writing in American English to determine whether a compound adjective after a noun needs to be hyphenated?

Comment: The reason your bold didn’t work is that you indented the quote by four space characters—that is the markup for a block of _computer code_, in which HTML and markup characters like asterisks and underscores are not parsed as such, but instead written out as simple characters. I’ve fixed the quote to be an actual blockquote now, where markup works as usual.

Comment: "MY QUESTION IS: Do you do that too?" can make this a POB.

Comment: "middle class" in "the neighborhood is middle class" is not an adjective. "Up-to-date" is a different case. Its adjective form is always hyphenated.

Comment: @Kris. I have no idea what POB means. Someone responded to my other question (for BrE) saying I should not use "you". I said I will in the future. I'm new here. This question was difficult to write in language that is clear. Will you bear with me?

Comment: @Kris. I agree the words "middle class" exist as both noun and adjectival phrases. It seems pretty obvious to me that for this use it is functioning to describe the neighborhood.

Comment: POB = Primarily Opinion Based, which is off-topic on ELU.   It is a noun phrase in that sentence. You could look at it as a compound noun if you like. HTH.

Comment: @RossMurray POB is “primarily opinion based”. The restriction on who can answer is unnecessary as a good answer will not just be backed by an opinion; it will use sources like corpora, which can be wielded by anyone, no matter their dialect.

Comment: I understand POB now. I will do my best to avoid it in the future. IN THIS CASE, It started from the first words of my question here, and the very similar question addressed to those who use BrE. I began both with, "For those who ...", meaning nothing more than site users should choose which of my two site questions they should choose if they have an answer. My use of "you" later flowed from that as I worked hard to write in a correct and natural style that very specifically stated my meaning ... BUT, as I said, next time I'll know better.

Comment: There was once a question here asking which respected dictionary best reflected 'American usage'. An answer, and I seem to remember that this was uncontested, was the OED. They research usage in the US as well as in the UK, and there are more Anglophones in the US. / Please be aware that 'the Oxford Dictionary' is almost as ambiguous as 'the Oxford college'. Perhaps more so.

Comment: Would you concur with this? I don't really trust any of them to be "right". I trust OED more than the others. As someone who uses both BrE and AmE regularly, I appreciate it identifies any differences its research detects. MOSTLY, I just need SOME TOOLS so that I get the same answer every time I look something up - even if it is that damn, awful CMOS. :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, however interesting, it is not a question in the terms of SE EL & U but an attempt to elicit an on-line poll.

Comment: I am edit this and the other one now.

Answer (score 1):

I **think** I've found the reasons behind the apparent anomaly I detected.

- In both BrE and AmE, compound adjectives are usually hyphenated before nouns but not after. There is one major difference for BrE. They also hyphenate after nouns when the compound includes a verb participle.
- That leads to a difference in the way BrE and AmE dictionaries show compound adjectives.
- AmE dictionaries show them with the hyphenated form. That alerts users hyphens are required before nouns; they assume users know that hyphens are dropped after nouns.
- BrE dictionaries show them with the hyphenated form **only** if they are hyphenated after nouns (usually because they contain a verb participle); the dictionaries assume users will know the mere listing of a multi-word entry in the dictionary is enough to conclude it is a compound, so if it is an adjective it must then have hyphens inserted when before nouns.

I was unfortunate is coming across an example "out of left field" when I first noticed AmE and BrE dictionaries mean different things when they list compound adjectives with the hyphenated form.

I stumbled across the example "middle-class".

I will investigate this further, but I think the OED treats that as an anomaly - it is hyphenated after nouns despite not having a verb participle. My **guess** is they chose that to achieve consistency with "working-class". That seems plausible and there is no grammatical reason they should treat it that way.

Finally, I have a logical reason why AmE and BrE dictionaries **should** have a fundamental difference in the way they list compound adjectives. I'm surprised I had never heard this mentioned before. I've been very active for about two years in an online chat room for authors of fiction. We have "discussed" just about every other aspect of grammar and punctuation over that period - at great length.